# Run function again after x amount seconds

Tags: javascript

I would like to re run a the same function after x amount of seconds.
the X changes every time the function is ran like the example i have provided below but the code below does not wait half a second before fireing the function again, it just instantly runs the function in an infinite loop

```
test();
var interval = 500
function test() {
    interval = interval + 500;
    console.log("1");
    setTimeout(test(), interval);
}
```

Comment: *Pass* the function, don't *call* it: `setTimeout(test, interval);`.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
setTimeout(test(), interval);
```

to

```
setTimeout(test, interval);
```

`test()` calls the function immediately.